# Filling of blank cells with zero using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FillEmptyCell()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sht.Activate

    Set rng = Range(Range("C12"), Range("AD" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count))

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = "0"
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to fill my blank spaces in sheet with zero dynamically.However,
I don't want this to fill zeroes in row that have no data. can someone help please?

Comment: This does the same as what your code does    `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("C12"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AD" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = 0`

Comment: Did you want to loop through column C and see if each row has data in it?

Comment: Yeah b column has some date that is being dumped from another sheet dynamically,so if B column has no date,The data corresponding to date that is being filled from C to AD should also have nothing Only if there is date and no value is there corresponding to each columns then I want those blank cells zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how this works,

```
Sub ZeroStuff()
    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set rng = .Range("C12:C" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

        For Each c In rng.Cells
            .Range(c.Offset(, 1), c.Offset(, 27)) = 0
        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is selecting even the rows that have no data in any cell.My code does the same. The columns are fixed from C12:AD12 but the rows are dynamic.I don't want zeroes for rows with no data.

Comment: If {sht.Activate} I do this instead, Range("c12:ad12"). Select Set rng= Range(Selection,Selection.End(xlDown)) then the for loop,,,, it only fills the C12:AD12 and a row below it with blankspaces with zero.Why it isn't going going tills the rows down with Atleast a data in one cell?

Comment: How can I use a while loop where if the row has date information in b column then all the blank cells corresponding to that row are filled with zero

Comment: I want it like From: 03/03/2016 To: 30/03/2016 but the date format isn't working,its giving numbers like From:  42256 To: 42272,something like this.